# What all VBScript operations are not allowed in HTA

Tags: macros, vbscript, scripting, vb6, hta

I want to develop a script using `hta` which will mainly interact with an `excel` file for data transaction. I developed earlier this using Excel `macro` but I want to do the same with `hta` also for `learning` purpose.

Now, problem is I can see few `vbscript` operations are not allowed within `hta` e.g. `echo`. Can someone give me a `list` of such operations/keywords which are not applicable in `hta`. Is there a better way to achieve this?

I code in Core Java hence did not try VB/.net!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript is VBScript whether you execute it under the WScript or the Mshta/Ie host. Not having the WScript host, means no WScript.Echo - and no WScript.Arguments.Unnamed.Count, WScript.Whatever.... either.

**But:** VBA is not VBScript. So don't expect [those features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30593abb%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to work in a .HTA.

Comment: True enough.  No WSH, no WScript object, so none of its methods and properties.  Of course MSHTA brings along its own object model to work with.